# Big realtime dataset in Qt

Tags: qt, listview, dataset, virtualization, bigdata

The task is to display a big dataset (with constant real-time update) in Qt application. Say, up to 100'000 rows with about 20 fields in each row.

Using ListView with such amount of items obviously leads to very slow scrolling and so on.
In C#/WPF I could use so called "virtualization", when list displays only visible items. Is there in Qt any analogs of list controls with virtualization? Or maybe there are some other better ways to reach to goal in Qt, isn't there?

Comment: the model-view widgets are built for this

Comment: Have a look at the [cacheBuffer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-listview.html#cacheBuffer-prop) property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is `QListView`, it has some bug and it doesn't recycle items (it creates all items even those outside of visible area) and this kills performance.
Replace it with `QTableView` should fix the problem. You can tweak it to make it visually similar to the list.

Comment: Actually, I've tried QListView as well: I took example application from Qt Creator gallery "Qt Quick Controls", which uses QTableView, and increased number of items to 100'000. Scrolling became very slow.

Comment: No, you mixing different things, "Qt Quick" is completely different issue! Just try replace `QListView` with `QTableView` in YOUR code which doesn't use "qt quick".

Comment: `QListView` is a `QWidget` and is not a part of Qt Quick. Qt quick is new alternative set of UI elements. `QWidget` is old way for creating UI.

Comment: I took standard example ("Qt Quick Controls"), which uses QTableView, replaced only one number (number of items 100 => 100'000), and launched it. And it is slow. There's no QListView at all. Simple table view with many items and slow scrolling...

Comment: Hm, well, i'm totally new to Qt, so I could easily mix unmixable :-) So, can I use QListView in qml?

Comment: Looks like misunderstanding, so your code uses QML (you have *.qml files in your project). If yes then add this information to your question (don't forget a new tag).

Comment: see the difference between: [QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtableview.html) and [Qt Quick TableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-tableview.html).

Comment: Marek, I'm trying different approaches to find the best one. I have no "my project" yet. My first attempt was to use QListView, second - "Qt Quick Controls" with QML. As far as I can understand, I should use "old way" and QTableView to achieve good performance.

Comment: 1) Use QTableView. 2) Do not use widgets as rows. 3) Use fast models. Possible you need to create your own, based on QAbstractItemModel.